# Setting php values to keys using an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, key

Lets say I have an array:

```
array("item1", "item2", "item3");
```

And 3 variables:

```
$value1 = ""; 
$value2 = "";
$value3 = "";
```

How can I manipulate this array by changing their values to keys so that item1, item2, item3 are now keys and then set new values to them which are value1, value2, value3 in order.

I.e. it should end up with:

```
array("item1" => $value1, "item2" => $value2, "item3" => $value3);
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the direct approach to create a new array?

```
$myArray = [
    "item1" => $value1,
    "item2" => $value2,
    "item3" => $value3,
];
```

This cannot really be "automated", since there is no relation between the key strings ("item1" ...) and the variable names ("value1" ...).

The only feature that *may* come in handy here is the `array_combine()` function:

```
<?php
$keys = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
$value1 = "one";
$value2 = "two";
$value3 = "three";

$output = array_combine($keys, [$value1, $value2, $value3]);
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

> Array
>   (
>       [item1] => one
>       [item2] => two
>       [item3] => three
>   )

Answer (score 0):

you can do many solution for insert values into the array like this:

```
//array_push($arrayVar, <your Value> );
$arrayVar = array();

array_push($arrayVar, $value1 );
array_push($arrayVar, $value2 ); //ETC
```

but if you want to **Read** your array and save the Array value in your Variable you need to do something like this;

```
$ArrayVar = Array("item1", "item2", "item3");
//so you have 3 items values in 3 position  of 0 to 2, you can use it like this
$value1 = $ArrayVar[0]; //This Array position is "item1" so you can print it
Echo $value1;
```

output

```
item1
```

> I hope you are useful, and whatever you are looking for otherwise if
>   not I did not understand your request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

store your values in an array and use array_combine() method of php.

like

```
echo array_combine($itemarray,$valuearray);
```